# Python Plotly Polar Chart Slice Alignment

Tags: python, graph, plotly, plotly-python

So what I'm trying to do is create a polar chart using plotly. However, it needs to look similar to a pie chart, where each `label` is given a slice of the circle. Currently the polar chart works fine, if I divide the circle into equal slices. But, when I try to give them a slice corresponding to the `weights` it doesn't work out too well, as it tends to overlap or leave spaces between each slice. This is mainly due to the Theta.

Can someone please explain where I've gone wrong?

`Ratings` - Max value is 5, Min value is 1. This is used to determine the length of the slice in the polar chart.

`Weights` - Max value is 100, Min value is 1. This is used to determine the width of the slice in the polar chart.

`Labels` - To identify each slice.

### When equally splitting the circle

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px


ratings = [3, 2, 5, 1, 2]
weights = [65, 79, 81, 98, 58]
labels = ["Strength", "Intelligence", "Dexterity", "Wisdom", "Stealth"]

def make_barpolar(ratings, weights, labels=None, colors=None, layout_options = None, **fig_kwargs):
    # infer slice angles
    num_slices = len(weights)
    theta = [(i) * 360 / num_slices for i in range(0, num_slices)]
    width = [360 / num_slices for _ in range(num_slices)]
    
    # optionally infer colors
    if colors is None:
        color_seq = px.colors.qualitative.Safe
        color_indices = range(0, len(color_seq), len(color_seq) // num_slices)
        colors = [color_seq[i] for i in color_indices]

    if layout_options is None:
        layout_options = {}

    if labels is None:
        labels = ["" for _ in range(num_slices)]
        layout_options["showlegend"] = False

    # make figure
    barpolar_plots = [go.Barpolar(r=[r], theta=[t], width=[w], name=n, marker_color=[c], **fig_kwargs)
                      for r, t, w, n, c in zip(ratings, theta, width, labels, colors)]
    
    fig = go.Figure(barpolar_plots)
    
    # additional layout parameters
    fig.update_layout(**layout_options)
    
    return fig


layout_options = {"title": "My Stats",
                  "title_font_size": 24,
                  "title_x": 0.5,
                  "legend_x": 0.85,
                  "legend_y": 0.5,
                  "polar_radialaxis_ticks": "",
                  "polar_radialaxis_showticklabels": False,
                  "polar_radialaxis_range": [0, max(ratings)],
                  "polar_angularaxis_ticks": "",
                  "polar_angularaxis_showticklabels": False}

fig = make_barpolar(ratings, weights, labels, layout_options=layout_options, opacity = 0.7)
fig.show()
```

[Polar Chart 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LNiW.png)

### When using the `weights` to calculate the width and theta

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px


ratings = [3, 2, 5, 1, 2]
weights = [65, 79, 81, 98, 38]
labels = ["Strength", "Intelligence", "Dexterity", "Wisdom", "Stealth"]

def make_barpolar(ratings, weights, labels=None, colors=None, layout_options = None, **fig_kwargs):
    # infer slice angles
    
    angles = [(weight / sum(weights) * 360) for weight in weights]
    theta = []
    num_slices = len(ratings)
    theta = []
    for index, angle in enumerate(angles):
        if index < len(angles)-1:
            if index == 0:
                theta.append(0)
            theta.append(theta[index] + angle)
    width = angles
    
    # optionally infer colors
    if colors is None:
        color_seq = px.colors.qualitative.Safe
        color_indices = range(0, len(color_seq), len(color_seq) // num_slices)
        colors = [color_seq[i] for i in color_indices]

    if layout_options is None:
        layout_options = {}

    if labels is None:
        labels = ["" for _ in range(num_slices)]
        layout_options["showlegend"] = False

    # make figure
    barpolar_plots = [go.Barpolar(r=[r], theta=[t], width=[w], name=n, marker_color=[c], **fig_kwargs)
                      for r, t, w, n, c in zip(ratings, theta, width, labels, colors)]
    
    fig = go.Figure(barpolar_plots)
    
    # additional layout parameters
    fig.update_layout(**layout_options)
    
    return fig


layout_options = {"title": "My Stats",
                  "title_font_size": 24,
                  "title_x": 0.5,
                  "legend_x": 0.85,
                  "legend_y": 0.5,
                  "polar_radialaxis_ticks": "",
                  "polar_radialaxis_showticklabels": False,
                  "polar_radialaxis_range": [0, max(ratings)],
                  "polar_angularaxis_ticks": "",
                  "polar_angularaxis_showticklabels": False}

fig = make_barpolar(ratings, weights, labels, layout_options=layout_options, opacity = 0.7)
fig.show()
```

[Polar Chart 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KXjP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are assuming that `theta` sets the location of one edge of a radial sector when it is in fact the *center* of that radial sector.  Here is your code but with a calculation of `theta` that accounts for this difference:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px


ratings = [3, 2, 5, 1, 2]
weights = [65, 79, 81, 98, 38]
labels = ["Strength", "Intelligence", "Dexterity", "Wisdom", "Stealth"]

def make_barpolar(ratings, weights, labels=None, colors=None, layout_options = None, **fig_kwargs):
    # infer slice angles
    
    angles = [(weight / sum(weights) * 360) for weight in weights]
    num_slices = len(ratings)
    theta = [0.5 * angle for angle in angles]
    for index, angle in enumerate(angles):
        for subsequent_index in range(index + 1, len(angles)):
            theta[subsequent_index] += angle
    width = angles
    
    # optionally infer colors
    if colors is None:
        color_seq = px.colors.qualitative.Safe
        color_indices = range(0, len(color_seq), len(color_seq) // num_slices)
        colors = [color_seq[i] for i in color_indices]

    if layout_options is None:
        layout_options = {}

    if labels is None:
        labels = ["" for _ in range(num_slices)]
        layout_options["showlegend"] = False

    # make figure
    barpolar_plots = [go.Barpolar(r=[r], theta=[t], width=[w], name=n, marker_color=[c], **fig_kwargs)
                      for r, t, w, n, c in zip(ratings, theta, width, labels, colors)]
    
    fig = go.Figure(barpolar_plots)
    
    # additional layout parameters
    fig.update_layout(**layout_options)
    
    return fig


layout_options = {"title": "My Stats",
                  "title_font_size": 24,
                  "title_x": 0.5,
                  "legend_x": 0.85,
                  "legend_y": 0.5,
                  "polar_radialaxis_ticks": "",
                  "polar_radialaxis_showticklabels": False,
                  "polar_radialaxis_range": [0, max(ratings)],
                  "polar_angularaxis_ticks": "",
                  "polar_angularaxis_showticklabels": False}

fig = make_barpolar(ratings, weights, labels, layout_options=layout_options, opacity = 0.7)
fig.show()
```

which gives

[image: polar_bar_correct_alignment]

If you want to shift everything back so that the light blue sector is pointing directly to the right, you could always subtract `0.5 * angle[0]` from every element of `theta` as one additional minor step.

__

P.S. Very high quality post for a first-time poster.  Bravo!

Comment: Thank you very much!!! :D   

I was worried my question made no sense, as this was a small example of what I'm currently working on. There's not a lot of information about these kind of graphs online, and the documentation isn't that helpful.

Comment: @Frodnar, how could you color the bars based on a certain array of values e.g. a colorscale? I've been trying to pass an array of values to but also tried to update the trace.

`fig.update_traces(marker={
        "colorscale": px.colors.sequential.Reds,
         "showscale": True,
         "color": df['winrate'],
         "line_color": None,
         "line_width": 1,
         "cmin": df['winrate'].min(),
         "cmax": df['winrate'].max(),
})`

but I keep getting a greyish nuance of colors.

Comment: @Geosphere. For a more complex case like this, why not just set the colors correctly when you make the plot the first time around? Without more context (i.e. your full code) I can't really troubleshoot.  Probably the best thing to do would be to post this as a new question with all of the context explained and then tag me right away in the comments if you want me to answer.

Comment: @Frodnar. I've posted my full code here: https://community.plotly.com/t/updating-barpolar-color-using-updating-traces/62857 but then again I could ask the question again on SO. 
Essentially, I'm using your code as a starting point.

Comment: @Geosphere Apologies for the delay.  I replied over on plotly forums with slightly adjusted code that achieves what you're asking.